# Line in front of text on input

Tags: html, css, focus

How Is The Line  |  That is in Front of the text When Typing in a Text Input Called?

I have been trying to find it's name' but i just cant describe it well enough for google to help me.
I have put an Auto-Focus on html text input tag

```
<input id="search" class="search" type="text" onkeyup="search()" 
placeholder="Bikes" name="search" autofocus="autofocus"/>
```

but this line that fades in and out every second drives Me crazy...

Can you please tell me how is it called, And if my intention Even possible?

Comment: It's the cursor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is called the cursor focus.

#### Edit

> *Is There a way to remove it from an HTML input When on focus? Or At least show it only when typing?*

Yes, take a look:

```css
input {
  color: transparent;
  text-shadow: 0 0 0 #000; /* color of your input */
}
```

```html
<input id="search" class="search" type="text" />
```

Comment: Thank You! you really helped me.

Comment: Is There a way to remove it from an HTML input When on focus? Or At least show it only when typing?